# Role of macrostates in formulation of phase space density

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

This is from page 58 of Kardar's "Statistical Physics of Particles":

> Therefore, there must be a very large number of microstates corresponding to the same macrostate $M$. 
> This many-to-one correspondence suggests the introduction of a statistical ensemble of microstates. Consider $N$ copies of a particular macrostate, each described by a different representative point $\mu(t)$ in the phase space $\Gamma$. 
> Let $dN(p,q,t)$ equal the number of representative points in an infinitesimal volume
> $d\Gamma = \Pi_{i=1}^N d^3 \overrightarrow{p_i} d^3 \overrightarrow{q_i}$ around the point $(p,q)$. 
> A phase space density $\rho(p,q,t)$ is then defined by $$\rho(p,q,t) \ d\Gamma=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{dN(p,q,t)}{N}$$

Now, doesn't this mean that we are only defining the phase space density for a particular macrostate $M$? Why not pose a more general definition as ratio of microstates in that volume to the total number of microstates?

Furthermore, is it always the case that for a given macrostate, it's phase density over  a given volume will be the same as that for every other macrostate? If not, then how is this formulation consistent?